# What should I do with these error when I try to install strtotime?

Tags: python, installation, pip, strtotime

When I try to install strtotime, its gives error, how can I solve that?

```
  Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
  Collecting strtotime
  Using cached strtotime-1.0.4.zip (600 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\altanhaligur\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u_jk3g0r\strtotime_8280b3f4653f4ee4b0b0dcf4456e7ea4\setup.py", line 33, in <module>
          extra_compile_args = sysconfig.get_config_var("CFLAGS").split()
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I think there are some errors about my python setup but do not want to delete everything and setup again, is there any ways to fix that?

Comment: First off;  Its a bug in the strtotime setup.py.  It should actually check that the value is there before "splitting" but the main issue is most likely this: You dont have working c/c++ compiler installed.  See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: @rasjani should I complete steps at the link or just need to install one c/c++ compiler?

Comment: @rasjani downloaded visual studio but still I got same error